# run sh file at startup with cmd - able to see it

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, sh, startup

I'm trying to run a sh file that will run at startup on raspberry pi 
this is what I  have done so far :

1. create a start.sh file

   ```
   #/bin/bash
   java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/HelloWorld.jar
   ```
2. made it executable

   ```
   > chmod +x ./home/pi/Documents/start.sh
   ```
3. create a HelloWorld.jar in the desktop

   ```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class HelloWorld {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           System.out.println("Hello - the device is UP and running now :-)");

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           String tmp = scanner.nextLine();

           System.exit(0);
       }

   }
   ```

now when I run the `start.sh` in cmd - everything is working 
so the jar+sh file are O.K.

but now what? 
I have try to put the command in `rc.lcoal`

```
sudo '/home/pi/Documents/start.sh'

exit 0
```

didn't work

try to put in in `crontab -e`

```
@reboot sudo /home/pi/Documents/start.sh
```

also didn't work

what am I missing ?

I want\need to see see the cmd open and wait for my respone

Thanks ,

Comment: add execute permission to the file please

Comment: I'm a newbie at pi\linux . so please tell me which command do you wnat me to run?   Thanks ,

Comment: scripts that are run by the startup process do not run in an interactive shell which is required to have input from the user. I don't think you can have an interactive prompt from your program.

Comment: chmod +x start.sh should do

Comment: mmm.... so I can know if my java file is running? or if I have any problem ? must be a way to see the command line of the code , no?

Comment: Do you see `Hello - the device is UP and running now :-)` in some log or on the startup screen somewhere?

Comment: @Satya - I have done it , (look at number 2 of the post)

Comment: @zapl - nope , don't see it anywhere .

Comment: how are you running it now after making it executable , is there an entry in crontab for it ?

Comment: yes , I wrote it in the post - I have try to put the command in crontab and rc.local - nothing is working ....

Comment: put the file in /etc/init.d and restart your system

Comment: just to be sure(and save time) - I remove all the refernce from rc.local and crontab, and then add this line to init.d ?   sudo '/home/pi/Documents/start.sh'

Comment: just copy the file in /etc/init.d directory

Comment: start.sh: Error opening file '/etc/init.d/start.sh': Permission denied ??

Comment: check for file permissions

Comment: I have copy using this command :    sudo mv /home/pi/Documents/start.sh /etc/init.d/
  but after reboot - didn't work

Comment: I think I will create a log file that will show me if it's on and continue from there.... I guess there are things you can't do in linux :-O

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `sudo` in `rc.local`. Everything in `rc.local` is executed as `root`.

Maybe `rc.local` is not run at all. Modern systems foozled by systemd may not start it. See [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd). You can add the command `logger -t rc.local test` to your `rc.local` and check with `sudo grep rc.local /var/log/syslog`, if `rc.local` gets started.

Comment: rc.local is working because I have add output to file in the hava code - and I can see it's adding line every startup.... maybe it's like @zapl said , can't see the cmd in startup(while in windows you can.....) , maybe you have another idea?